# AKS Cluster failed with Message="Default route 0.0.0.0/0 has a next hop of Internet but only next hops VA or Vnet gateway are allowed?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Currently i'm working on Terraform AKS Cluster creation with kubenet and User defined route (UDR) based under corporate network(I'm using existing subnet) and associating route-table to subnet. i was able  provisioned cluster Until kubernetes orchestration version 1.15. Azure now stopped supporting it. Whenever i've upgraded to latest version to 1.17 or 1.18 the cluster provision failing with below error information .

I've associated default route "0.0.0.0/0" and next_hop_type as Internet then i'm getting below error. May be i'm missing somewhere but not sure what i've done wrongly.

> Original Error: Code="RouteTableInvalidNextHop" Message="Default route
> 0.0.0.0/0 has a next hop of Internet but only next hops of VirtualAppliance or VirtualNetworkGateway are allowed. Please see
> http://aka.ms/aks/outboundtype for more details

Here is my code snippet

```
provider "azurerm" {
    version = "~> 2.15"
    features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "aks" {
    name     = var.resource_group
    location = var.location
}
#fetch existing subnet 
data "azurerm_subnet" "aks" {
    name                 = var.subnetname
    virtual_network_name = var.virtual_network_name
    resource_group_name  = var.vnet_resource_group
}

resource "azurerm_route_table" "aks"{
    name                          = "aks" #var.subnetname
    resource_group_name           = azurerm_resource_group.aks.name
    location                      = azurerm_resource_group.aks.location
    disable_bgp_route_propagation = false

    route{
        name                = var.route_name
        address_prefix      = var.route_address_prefix
        next_hop_type       = var.route_next_hop_type
    }
        route{
        name                    = "default_route"
        address_prefix          = "0.0.0.0/0"
        next_hop_type           = "Internet"
        #next_hop_in_ip_address  = "10.65.27.1"
    }

}
resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "aks" {
    subnet_id      = data.azurerm_subnet.aks.id
    route_table_id = azurerm_route_table.aks.id
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "aks" {
    subnet_id                 = data.azurerm_subnet.aks.id
    network_security_group_id = var.network_security_group
}
resource "null_resource" "previous" {}

resource "time_sleep" "wait_90_seconds" {
    depends_on = [null_resource.previous]

    create_duration = "90s"
}

# This resource will create (at least) 30 seconds after null_resource.previous
resource "null_resource" "next" {
    depends_on = [time_sleep.wait_90_seconds]
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
    name                    = azurerm_resource_group.aks.name
    resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.aks.name
    location                = azurerm_resource_group.aks.location
    dns_prefix              = "akstfe"   #The dns_prefix must contain between 3 and 45 characters, and can contain only letters, numbers, and hyphens. It must start with a letter and must end with a letter or a number.
    kubernetes_version      = "1.18.8"
    private_cluster_enabled = false
    node_resource_group     = var.node_resource_group
    
    api_server_authorized_ip_ranges = [] #var.api_server_authorized_ip_ranges
    default_node_pool {
        enable_node_public_ip   = false
        name                    = "agentpool" 
        node_count              = var.node_count
        orchestrator_version    = "1.18.8"
        vm_size                 = var.vm_size
        os_disk_size_gb         = var.os_disk_size_gb
        vnet_subnet_id          = data.azurerm_subnet.aks.id
    }

    linux_profile {
        admin_username = var.admin_username
        ssh_key {
            key_data = var.ssh_key
        }
    }
    service_principal {
        client_id     = var.client_id
        client_secret = var.client_secret
    }

    role_based_access_control {
        enabled = true
    }
    network_profile {
        network_plugin = "kubenet"
        #dns_service_ip     = "172.17.1.10"
        #service_cidr       = "172.16.0.0/14"
        pod_cidr           = "172.40.0.0/16"
        network_policy     = "calico"
        outbound_type      = "userDefinedRouting"
        load_balancer_sku  = "Standard"

    }
            addon_profile {
            aci_connector_linux {
            enabled = false
        }

        azure_policy {
            enabled = false
        }

        http_application_routing {
            enabled = false
        }

        kube_dashboard {
            enabled = false
        }

        oms_agent {
            enabled = false
        }
    }
    depends_on = [azurerm_subnet_route_table_association.aks]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`0.0.0.0/0` with next hop to internet doesn't make any sense. its a default anyway. just drop it.

thats pretty much what the error tells you anyway.

Comment: i've taken out  0.0.0.0/0 Unfortunately default route was not there when i'm running through terraform , i'm getting below error

" Original Error: Code="RouteTableMissingDefaultRouteError" Message="Default route 0.0.0.0/0 missing from route table"

Comment: Were you able to resolve this ? if you were what was the solution please ?